# Content script only executed on page load (& reload)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to run a content script on the site [di.se](http://www.di.se/). However, my issue is that it's only executed on the initial page load - not on links clicks (e.g. articles).

I know there are some similar threads out there, but they suggest that the page alters its URL by the [window.history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) API, which doesn't seems to be the case here, as far as I can tell.

TL;DR: I need your help figuring out why the content script doesn't execute on page links.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "version": "0.1",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["http://www.di.se/*"],
          "js": ["jquery-1.11.3.min.js", "script.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**script.js**

```
alert('test');
```

Comment: The site uses frames as you can see in the Inspector. Try adding `"all_frames": true` as per [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: @wOxxOm Aaha! I completly overlooked that - thanks! Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site uses frames as you can see in the Inspector.

To autoinsert the content script into all frames add `"all_frames": true` as per the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": .........,
    "js": ..............,
    "all_frames": true
}]
```